# Localization not working in angularJS using $translate service. Labels not getting fetched from properties file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to fetch data from properties file and want to display in html. I am using $translate service provided by angular js. My page is getting loaded before fetching data from property file thats why I am not getting values.

This is my html class

```
<h2><span>{{::welcome}} {{::user.firstName}},</span></h2>
<h3><span>{{::passwordRequest}}</span></h3>
<br>
<label class="label-bold">{{::userName}}</label>
<br><label for="">{{::user.userName}}</label>
```

[image]

This is my javascript class
I am using $translate service of angular to fetch data from properties file

```
$scope.welcome = $translate.instant('label.welcome');
$scope.passwordRequest = $translate.instant('label.changepassword.request');
$scope.userName = $translate.instant('label.username');
$scope.pswd = $translate.instant('label.password');
```

This is the value in property file

```
label.username = Username
label.welcome = Welcome
label.password= Password
label.changepassword.request = You've requested to reset your password.
```